# How to make two or more buttons active

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, button

I need to make user cards where on clicking the follow button it changes color and name and adds 1 to following. I receive such users from API , 12 users, and I need to be able to choose more than 1 user, how can I do it, I can't figure it out.
thinking to try redux

but I can't understand how to mark the button to record in the store
That my code where I make a request. then I record it in "user", and through map, I render all the cards

````
export const UserList = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(2);


  const getUsersFromAPI = async () => {
    const user = await fetchUsers();
    setUsers(user);
  };

  const fetchNextPage = async () => {
    setPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1);
    const usersNext = await nextPageUsers(page, 3);
    setUsers(prevUser => [...prevUser, ...usersNext]);
    if (page === 4) {
      setPage(1);
      await nextPageUsers(page, 3);
      return;
    }

    return usersNext;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsersFromAPI();
  }, []);

  
# const followind = (id, e) => {
# 
# const userIdx = users.findIndex(user => user.id === id);
# 
# if (userId === id) {
# setUserId(null);
# users[userIdx].followers--;
# 
# return;
#     }
# 
# setUserId(id);
# users[userIdx].followers++;
#   };

  return (
    <div>
      {users && (
        <ul className={css.list}>
          {users.map(user => {
            return (
              <li key={user.id} className={css.containerItem}>
                <div className={css.space}>
                  <button type="button" className={css.imageLogo}></button>
                  <div className={css.upperPart}></div>
                  <div className={css.middleLine}>
                    <img
                      className={css.userFoto}
                      src={user.avatar}
                      alt={user.name}
                    ></img>
                  </div>
                  <div className={css.lowerPart}>
                    <p className={css.ps}> {user.tweets} Tweets</p>

                    <p className={css.ps}>
                      {' '}
                      {user.followers.toLocaleString('en-US')}
                      Followers
                    </p>

                    ***<button
                      id={user.id}
                      className={
                        userId === user.id ? css.btnPress : css.btnFollow
                      }
                      type="button"
                      onClick={e => followind(user.id, e)}
                    >
                      {userId === user.id ? 'Following' : 'Follow'}
                    </button>***
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      )}
      {page <= 4 && (
        <button type="button" onClick={fetchNextPage}>
          Next
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i correctly understand your problem...

You need a parameter for "status of following"

To do this, you need to add the new parameter to objects in the users array, for example, by calling  this parameter "followingStatus", and change it's boolean value on click

You need to return the new array to your useState hook

```js
const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    {
      id: '1',
      followers: 0,
      ...
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      followers: 56,
      ...
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      followers: 1,
      ...
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      followers: 4,
      ...
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      followers: 9,
      ...
    },
  ]);
  const [usersFollowingIds, setUserFollowingIds] = useState({'2': true});
```

```js
const followind = (id, followingStatus) => {
    setUserFollowingIds((prevState) => {
      const newState = {...prevState};

      if (followingStatus) {
        delete newState[id];
      } else {
        newState[id] = true;
      }

      return newState;
    });

    setUsers((prevState) => {
      return prevState.map((user) => {
        if (user.id === id) {
          return {
            ...user,
            followers: followingStatus ? --user.followers : ++user.followers,
          };
        }

        return user;
      });
    });
  };
```

```js
{users.map((user) => {
  const followingStatus = usersFollowingIds[user.id];

  return (
    <button key={user.id} id={user.id} className={followingStatus ? css.btnPress : css.btnFollow} type="button" onClick={() => followind(user.id, followingStatus)}>
      {followingStatus ? 'Following' : 'Follow'}
    </button>
  );
})}
```

Comment: sounds good, but I have a condition that the array of objects should be like this => {
  "name": "Simon Romaguera",
  "avatar": "https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/Qmd3W5DuhgHirLHGVixi6V76LhCkZUz6pnFt5AJBiyvHye/avatar/1066.jpg",
  "followers": 1,
  "tweets": 74,
  "id": "1"
 },
 {
  "name": "Myron Hegmann",
  "avatar": "https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/Qmd3W5DuhgHirLHGVixi6V76LhCkZUz6pnFt5AJBiyvHye/avatar/750.jpg",
  "followers": 2,
  "tweets": 43,
  "id": "2"
 },............

Comment: I changed my answer, try like this